# Adding Two Numbers using AJAX with a python script

Tags: python, ajax

I am trying to perform a very simple task here...adding two numbers entered on an HTML page. The result has to come from a python script . This has to be done using AJAX. SO I have created the following page with the javscript for ajax call as well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
function askServer() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var dataToSend = "?number1="+number1 + "&number2="+number2;
    req.open("GET","myScript.py",dataToSend,true);
    req.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    req.send();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The request has been sent.";
}
function handleServerResponse() {    
    if((req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200)) {
        var result = req.responseText;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The answer is : " + result + ".";
    } 
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter two numbers:
<input id="number1" type="number">
<input id="number2" type="number">
</p>
<p>To ask the server top add them, without refreshing the page, click this button:           <button onclick="askServer()">Ask the Server</button></p>
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I need some help with the python script. I know it would just require the two parameters in the query string ; add them and return.

Say I have created a .py file with the following statement

```
return "Hi".
```

The complete text "return 'HI!'" is returned as a result. I am just a python beginner.

Comment: which server setup do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This task can be simply done if you use a web framework.

Here is a huge list of Python web frameworks

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Using flask - http://flask.pocoo.org/

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/myScript.py')
def view_add_numbers():
    number_one = request.args.get('number1', '')
    number_two = request.args.get('number2', '')
    if number_one and number_two:
        return '%s' % (int(number_one) + int(number_two))
    else:
        return 'Fail'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You can create a better url and pass number1 and number2 in other way. Read the docs.